# How to extract data from a table that contains joins and insert it into table in another database?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, business-intelligence, ssis-2012

I want to extract data from a table that contains joins from database(db_name_1) and insert the data into another database(db_name_2) that contains the same table with the same fields with the same joints. Using SSIS.

Comment: the table it relates join with another table
I try to extract these data to another table but I distination errors foriegn key

Comment: no I have not added this identity function
how to add